# Google Chrome Unicode issue

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, unicode

Hi I'm having problem with google chrome browser when i read sinhala unicode fonts.  just week ago suddenly chrome failed to render sinhala font.

but for context it showing i'll post example

[image]

Comment: Do the full internationalization of your OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update Chrome to the latest version.
2. Enter 'chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write' in the chrome address bar and
   press enter.
3. Toggle the option using the hyper-link (Enable if disabled and vice-versa) it and relaunch.
4. Check whether it's fixed.
5. If not goto number 2 and follow the steps again. This time it will revert back to the original setting.
6. Relaunch and test.